# Grabbing anchor elements that link to a certain website

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to find any links on the page that link to a certain domain, and then get the links `href` tag.

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
foreach(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link in entryNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href='*site.com*']"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(imageLink.InnerHtml);
}
```

But I'm getting this exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I also tried `//a[@href=*site.com*]` with no luck, it said it was an invalid token.

What's the XPath expression that I need to find any links on the page which link to a certain domain? Also, how would I go about extracting their `href` attribute (in the same XPath expression if possible).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath has a `contains` method for that, so it's as easy as this:

```
var urls = new List<Uri>();
var url = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131954/");
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
  var doc = new HtmlDocument();
  doc.Load(client.OpenRead(url));
  var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href,'stackoverflow.com')]");
  foreach (var link in links)
  {
    var uri = new Uri(url, link.Attributes["href"].Value); //fixes relative Urls
    if (uri.Scheme.StartsWith("http"))
    {
      urls.Add(uri);
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine(urls);
}
```

Or you could use Linq for getting the links

```
var links = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
  .Where(a => a.Attributes["href"] != null
      && a.Attributes["href"].Value.ToLower().Contains("stackoverflow.com"));
```

Also it seems like you are matching from a child node, if you want to use that same XPath you'll have to add a dot at the beginning of the string `.//a[]`

Comment: Cheers, contains seems to be what I need :) However, when I use `//a[contains(@href,'site.com')` I get an invalid token exception.

Comment: hm, it works for me just fine, does the code i posted work for you? if not, what version of the Agility Pack are you using?

Comment: a wait, the xpath has to be `//a[contains(@href,'site.com')]`, yours is missing an `]`.